how to get dependency graphs - problems in generated code
I am trying to look at dependency graphs by setting MAGE_PROFILER=2, as explained here.
When I do, I get an error like

Fatal error: Declaration of Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\CacheManager\Logger::load(string $key) must be compatible with Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\CacheManager::load(string $key): ?array in /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Interception/Config/CacheManager/Logger.php on line 69

The problem is that the load method doesn't have a return type set.
I can fix the file in generated/ by hand, but there are many such errors -- and editing generated code by hand isn't sustainable in any case.
Do you need to do something special for generated code to include return type annotations?
Or is there a way to ignore the problem with type inconsistencies?
I've observed this problem both in a large production codebase as well as in a bare bones, nearly stock installation.  And with both php 8.2 and 8.1.
